# PyPDF2 - Unable to Get Past. A Large Corrupted File

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am working on checking for corrupted PDF in a file system. In the test I am running, there are almost 200k PDF's. It seems like smaller corrupted files alert correctly, but I ran into a large 15 MB file that's corrupted and the code just hangs indefinitely. I've tried setting Strict to False with no luck. It seems like it's the initial opening that's the problem. Rather than doing threads and setting a timeout (which I have tried in the past to little success), I'm hoping there's an alternative.

```
import PyPDF2, os
from time import gmtime,strftime

path = raw_input("Enter folder path of PDF files:")
t = open(r'c:\pdf_check\log.txt','w')
count = 1
for dirpath,dnames,fnames in os.walk(path):
    for file in fnames:
        print count
        count = count + 1
        if file.endswith(".pdf"):
            file = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
            try:
                PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file,'rb',warndest="c:\test\warning.txt")
            except PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError:
                curdate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
                t.write(str(curdate) + " " + "-" + " " + file + " " + "-" + " " + "fail" + "\n")
            else:
                pass
                #curdate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
                #t.write(str(curdate) + " " + "-" + " " + file + " " + "-" + " " + "pass" + "\n")
t.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with PyPDF2. I wasn't able to get it to work, however, I used pdfrw and it did not stop at this point and ran through all couple hundred thousand docs without issue.